# Django create a dict with values of a model field as key and model instance as value

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a model `Quest` and it has a field `type`. I want to have a dict that maps `type` to a list of `Quest`. My current way of doing it is just iterating over all the `Quest` objects and append them to the list.

```
from collections import defaultdict

quests = Quest.objects.all()
dictionary = defaultdict(list)
for quest in quests:
    dictionary[quest.type].append(quest)
```

I am wondering if Django `QuerySet` has a better way to do it. I looked up `aggregation()`, `value_list()` and `values()` but they don't seem to achieve what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any such django [`QuerySet`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/) functionality. You could, however, use the query to already order your quests by `type` so that you can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) in a `dict` comprehension without having to sort in Python:

```
from itertools import groupby

quests = Quest.objects.all().order_by('type')
dictionary = {k: list(g) for k, g in groupby(quests, key=lambda q: q.type)}
```